# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when calling foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

when using @foreach in MVC 4 I get the error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have called a list in outer loop and now am trying to call a list in inner loop.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
                        {
                           @:<tr>
                            <td>@item.Title</td>                                                                
                            <td>@item.Name</td>
                            <td>@item.Age</td> 

                             foreach (var user in Model.Company)
                             {
                                 <td>@user.CompanyName</td>
                             } 

                            @:</tr>                               
                        }
```

Comment: Believe it or not, there's more than one implementation of the MVC **pattern** in use in computing, in various different languages and technology stacks. I might **guess** that you're talking about ASP.Net MVC, with C# and Razor, but **I** shouldn't have to. Please edit your question and apply a few more targetted tags.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what the table is supposed to look like, but a few things. You don't need the @: near the opening and closing TR tags. Is it possible that a list of Companies was never mapped to the Model? You could try explicitly declaring it as a new list in the constructor of the Model. That would at least prevent it from blowing up. If it is always null, even when you know there is data, then im not sure what the issue would be.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `Model.Company` is null. Check this.

How do you fill this list?

And you can remove the `@:` there are not needed.